# Check User is Logged in or Nor in Web Browser Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I m trying to make one test app in windows phone 7.1 And I am using webBrowser control in my app and giving url of external website. User input login details in that form and press submit button. How I Can know the user is logged in.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the URL the user is being redirected to, using the WebBrowser.Navigating event. Check the NavigatingEventArgs.Uri property.

Then you just need to work out the page that the login page redirects to, and if the user is navigating to that then they have successfully logged in.

Comment: But Suppose If I have Login url Same as Default Page. Mean After Login The Page URL Doesnot Changes Then? Is There Any Way To Get Session or Cookies From Browser Control in WP7

Comment: No, you can't. If you have control over the web site in question you can raise the ScriptNotify event from Javascript to signify that the user is logged in.